# c# better option than datatable and arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable, excel-interop

I have an application to perform grouping, filtering, removing duplicates and lookup on data. The data that I'm working on will be exported to excel or csv files.

**Problem** is, its too slow. When I work with small files, like 10k-20k records, it takes almost a minute or two to perform the operation. But when I work with large files, I've tried with files containing 100k to 700k records, this takes a lot of time (more than an hour).

**What I've tried**: I have tried with Datatables and arrays. I usually prefer arrays over datatables as I found arrays are faster compared to datatables, but still there is a couple of minutes performance difference in this case.

**What I want**: Can anyone please suggest me a better way of doing this? I really don't want to use OLEDB or any other extra libraries to do this.

Please do let me know, if I've missed anything. I can provide the code if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you fetch all entities in memory first and then group/filter or is it running in your db query? Code would be a massive help here

Comment: Also, any asynchronous methods going on here, can we process multiple records at a time?

Comment: There are so many potential issues here (e.g. network-delay, IO-operations, query-optimization, ...) , which makes this question way to broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: " I can provide the code if needed" - yes please, its always needed

Comment: @andyb952: Nop! we can't process multiple records at a time. At least not while remove duplicates or lookup operations.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: Thanks for that. My application comes into picture after pulling the data from the database. So basically, first I have a button to pull the data from the source and than perform these operations.

Comment: That´s what andy ment. Why doing every sorting and filtering yourself, when your database can handle this far better?

Comment: Because the database is restricted to only select queries. where clause excluded. I can only download files.